# I encrypted an external hard drive using a laptop that's now irretrievably broken - have I lost the external hardrive my extension

Tags: hard-drive, external-hard-drive, encryption

I have basic computer literacy, and fear what I question might true - hugely grateful for any advice.

The hard drive was encrypted using VeraCrypt.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: “The hard drive was encrypted using VeraCrypt.” - So install Veracrypt and use the passphrase to decrypt the drive.

Comment: @Ramhound VeraCrypt can also use a file to decrypt the drive. If that file was stored on the laptop, then all hope is lost.

Comment: How exactly is the laptop broken anyway? You might be able to salvage its storage device (HDD or SSD).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The encryption process doesn't really bind the disk to the original computer in any way. All you need to unlock the VeraCrypt volume is the original password (though hopefully you didn't use a key file that's now lost).

If you did lose the unlock password, then you will not be able to access the encrypted data anymore, but the disk itself remains usable – the encryption process only changes what data was sent to the disk, but nothing about the disk itself. So if you want to start from scratch, the old VeraCrypt metadata can be simply erased and a standard partition table (or a new empty VeraCrypt volume) created in its place.

Comment: user1686, even if "N Godrich" did not use a key file, decryption requires not only your personal passphrase, but a readable header area as well because the personal passphrase gives access to the encrypted key that is located in the header. I am pointing this out as the user states "irretrievably broken" which might include a dammaged drive, which could include a dammaged header.

Comment: @r2d3: They only stated that the laptop was broken, not that the external HDD was.

Comment: Sorry, I missed the "external HD"!